# How to test "functions returning errors" using Jest and Typescript?

Tags: node.js, typescript, jestjs

### How to test fs.writeFile using Jest?

I want to test the following `fs.write` function using Jest

```js
async function saveFile(): Promise<void | Error> {
  fs.writeFile("./test.txt", (await newStockLength()).toString(), (err) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
      return err;
    }
    //file written successfully
    process.exit(0);
  });
}
```

My Test is:

```js
it("should run no mather what", async () => {
      const ran = await saveFile();
      expect(ran).resolves.not.toBe(Error);
    });
```

I want to see the error in my test if Node returns [an Error object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error).

How should I add Error Object to `Promise<void | ErrorObject >` in typescript?

#### If I use `Promise<void | Error>` and use `toBeNull`

```js
      expect(ran).resolves.toBeNull();
```

I get following error:

```
    expect(received).resolves.toBeNull()

    Matcher error: received value must be a promise

    Received has value: undefined
```

Comment: I think I need to use The throw statement instead of Error

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/781#issuecomment-193991055

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fs.writeFile` does not return a promise. `fs.writeFileSync` is a good synchronous alternative if you're OK with blocking the event loop.

It looks to me like your code isn't doing quite what you expect it to to. The `saveFile` function returns a `Promise`, and the result of the callback has nothing to do with the `Promise` that's returned, and you're not waiting for the write-function's work to happen. Working with callbacks & Promises in the same function can be a bit hairy, so Node comes with a [`util.promisify`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original) helper.

```
import {promisify} from "util";
const writeFileAsync = promisify(fs.writeFile);
async function saveFile (): Promise<void | Error> {
  try {
    await writeFileAsync(...);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    return err;
  }
}
```

Alternatively, you can do the same thing by returning a promise:

```
await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  fs.writeFile(..., (err) => {
    if (err) resolve(err);
    return resolve(null);
  })
})
```

In general, though, I'd recommend against functions that return errors like this. Having functions throw errors when they fail is a much more common, safe, and effective pattern.

Comment: do you recommend not to test  `fs.writeFile`? It turns out, I did not understand difference between `fs.writeFileSync` and  `fs.writeFile` .  `fs.writeFile` does not return a promise.
https://medium.com/@abdishire15/what-is-the-difference-between-fs-writefile-and-fs-writefilesync-3a2c3f2c516

Comment: I would test your _usage_ of nodejs provided modules, but I wouldn't test the nodejs modules themselves.

Comment: Some folks recommend writing unit tests to fully understand any module that you use. This tends to be overkill, but it does flush out misunderstandings (like this one)